# Getting to root

Tags: command-line, sudo, password, root, su

I've checked the question archive and can't find an exact answer to the following. I have just installed Ubuntu on a new PC.

While I'm fairly proficient in lumbering about in MSs operating console, obviously the Unix environment is quite different.

I need to run a command but when I su - to the root I am prompted for the password for permission to do so. This is the odd bit. When i enter the correct log on password it is rejected and I am returned to the same prompt from where I entered the su etc from. This is despite the password being the one that SUCCESSFULLY authorizes other system changes (such as installing new software like a virus checker etc). I can't get my head around this. It's the same password I created when setting up the system and, as advised, it allows root access in other ways, just not through the su - command.

Anyone help?

I have another question about mounting a volume but I won't ask that until I get this right as I will need to get to root to issue the command I suspect is needed to get this other matter sorted. Thanks in advance.

Peter

Answer (score 1):

Since root login is not possible by default because of security concerns you can do

```
sudo su
```

or

```
sudo -i
```

in terminal(<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>). Which then asks for your user password. This will be accepted because youre in the proper group called `sudoers`.

Typing

```
exit
```

will bring you back to your normal user.